# python strings islower() method

Tags: python

```
input :ash.capitalize()
output:'Abv dfgrjjdhjheyooadfhshfheyoohey2255'
input:ash.islower()
output:True
```

why is the output of `islower()` method true even though the first character of the "ash" string is in uppercase.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You call `ash.capitalize()`, which returns *a new string* (leaving the old one unchanged). So `ash.lower()` may or may not be true, you cannot tell by looking at the output of `ash.capitalize()`

Comment: Do this: `ash = ash.capitalize()`. Then the `islower()` test will work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47026581/8033585

Answer (score 0):

**ash.capitalize()** does not change the value of **ash** to **Abv dfgrjjdhjheyooadfhshfheyoohey2255** . Instead, it returns a string which needs to be stored in another variable. 
Hence, if we call `islower()` on `ash`, it is still all lower case. 
An example of how it should be done:-

```
   x = "abv dfgrjjdhjheyooadfhshfheyoohey2255";
   y = x.capitalize();
   print y.islower();
```

Documentation for the same:-

[capitalize function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=capitalize#str.capitalize)